# I want a program related to @Scheduled and @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: java, spring-boot

how to start @Scheduled when i get some id nd id is coreect so @Scheduled is start nd id is wrong so it check for particular id

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like you need to have some logic in your `@Scheduler` and that's it.